# Is it possible to have one project on one domain and use two frameworks (Yii and Yii2)?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

My site was written on Yii framework (v1) and now I would like to start to rewrite it using Yii2. My plan is do it step by step starting from simple, solitary parts.

But I can't understand how can I combine two frameworks in background of my visitors, is it possible at all ?
Assuming that I have php 5.4 (or if need 5.5) on server, ONE domain name with no subdomains.

**Eg:** site has modular structure (it's real so) and have modules: **news** and **articles**. I will rewrite news on Yii2 and articles stay using Yii,

*mysite.com/news* and *mysite.com/articles* - should show the same as before and visitors shouldn't notice that *news* uses another framework (url should be the same as before)

Question is: How can I reach it if it's possible ? Is anybody have practical solution or did it in real project ?

Comment: I expect so. Set up two apps within a project folder (two front controllers, both libraries via Composer) and then use `mod_rewrite` to selectively direct to one or the other via URL patterns.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing so and I can tell you: It goes way beyond what the tutorials mention. Especially if you opt to gradually convert the Controllers/Actions that output to the screen. It's been hell so far to keep everything working.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to config url rewrite in nginx or apache , yes, you can .

- Nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html
- Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The essence is match url with regex, base on the difference of url load different index.php of different framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You are looking for this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-yii-2-with-yii-1 but you should also take a look at other integrations too. You just have to modify your index.php and that will get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possibile, you can install both in a domain. Simply install the  Yii1 and Yii2 framework library in two separated sub diretcory.

Inside eg mysite.com/articles  the index.php is complaiant for a Yii1 app and inside mysite.com/news the index.php is complaiant for Yii2 app

Comment: news and articles are only two modules from about 50 in my site. And site have much more routes in UrlManager. How can I separate framworks with saving my urls in this case ? Where is entry point on main url of site (mysite.com) ?